# Field Recordings on vinyl

Tags: field-recording, inspiration, sound-art

So I just picked up a record at my local record shop called "Environments." It was recorded by field recordist Irving Solomon Teible. I came to find out that this was a whole series(11 to be exact). I have the first one which has "The Physiologically Ultimate Seashore" recorded at Coney Island and "Optimum Aviary" recorded at the Bronx Zoo, both 30mins long. I just ordered Environments 2 which I am really excited about and was wondering if you guys have any favorite field recordist records/cd's/mp3's that you like to listen to on your off time?

Here's the wiki link for more info on "Environments" if any of you are interested!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environments_(series)#Environments_2_.281970.29

Cheers,

jocé

Answer (score 0):

Sort of on-topic, the Pain and Gain sound crew printed sound effects onto vinyl and hired a DJ to scratch the sounds.

http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/the-sound-of-pain-and-gain

Answer (score 0):

I picked up 'Memories of Steam' a few years ago for cheap. It's really pretty.

http://www.discogs.com/No-Artist-Memories-Of-Steam/release/2291301

English steam locomotive sounds, recorded by Kenneth Granville Attwood using MD421s and AKG D224; released 1970 and reissued 1978.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I recommend Chris Watson's work and also suggest you look into the [World Soundscape Project](http://www.sfu.ca/~truax/wsp.html) and [Freesound](http://freesound.org).

Answer (score 0):

Some 10 years ago we threw away a few shelf meters of sound effects on vinyl.
No one wanted them, no one had time or interest to transfer them, and space was at a premium, so it all went into a big container...